# Negating Quantified statements

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

The problem I am working on is:

> Express each of these statements using quantifiers. Then
>   form the negation of the statement, so that no negation
>   is to the left of a quantifier. Next, express the negation in
>   simple English. (Do not simply use the phrase “It is not
>   the case that.”)
>
> a) Some old dogs can learn new tricks.
>   b)No rabbit knows calculus.
>
> c) Every bird can fly.
>
> d)There is no dog that can talk.
>
> e) There is no one in this class who knows French and
>   Russian.

---

I am having trouble with only two parts--namely, d) and e)

For d): $P(x)= x$ cannot talk

$\exists xP(x)$ Negating this, $\neg \exists xP(x) \rightarrow \forall x \neg P(x)$

This would read in English, "Every dog can talk". However, the answer is, "There is a dog that talks."

---

For e): $F(x)= x$ doesn't know French.$\qquad R(x)= x$ doesn't know Russian.

$\forall x(F(x) \wedge R(x)$ Negating this, $\neg \forall x(F(x) \wedge R(x) \rightarrow \exists x(\neg F(x) \vee \neg R(x))$ Translating this back into English: There is a person in class that knows French or Russian."

However the answer is, "There is someone in this class who knows French and Russian"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases you’re starting in the wrong place, translating the original statement into symbols incorrectly.

For (d) the original statement is essentially ‘There does not exist a dog that can talk’, i.e., $\neg\exists xP(x)$, where $P(x)$ is ‘$x$ *is a dog that can talk*’. Negating that gives you simply $\exists xP(x)$, ‘There is a dog that can talk’.

Similarly, assuming that the universe of discourse is this class, (e) is $\neg\exists\big(F(x)\land R(x)\big)$, where $F(x)$ is ‘$x$ *does know French*’ and $R(x)$ is ‘$x$ *does know Russian*’, so its negation is $\exists\big(F(x)\land R(x)\big)$ ‘There is someone in this class who knows French and Russian’.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem D

"There does not exist a dog that can talk."

Now, $P(x) = \text{x can talk}$, your domain, $D$, is all dogs.  Thus, the statement becomes:
$$\neg \exists x\in D \text{ such that } P(x)$$

I'm pretty sure you can negate the above.

Another approach is to read the statement as "All dogs cannot talk."  Then, $Q(x) = \text{x cannot talk}$, your domain, $D$, is all dogs.  Thus, the statement becomes:
$$\forall x\in D, Q(x)$$

### Problem E

This is similar.  Let me know if you need help with this one, and I'll edit my answer to include it.